# meaning of "Four hours north of San Francisco"

Tags: meaning

guys. I heard the sentence below in a American program and I confused a little bit.

> Four hours north of San Francisco is a place called Ferndale.

Does it means "It takes 4 hours from north of San Francisco to Ferndale?"
I don't understand "Four hours north of San Francisco" this part.

Thanks!

Comment: For better or for worse, in the US this is shorthand for *four hours by car*. Back in the day a fellow graduate student misjudged the distance described as *ten minutes from here* to mean *ten minutes walk*. *By car* is the default in the US and can thus be dropped. They are more specific, if they mean another method of transportation. Such as *half an hour on a bus*, *a 15 minute bike ride* et cetera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the place Ferndale is 4 hours away by driving from San Francisco in the north direction.

Comment: @julialee A slight nitpick. It doesn't necessarily have to mean that Ferndale is four hours north of San Francisco by *car*. Depending on the context it could be walking, biking or even flying. With no other context though "by car" is the most likely meaning.